why Resource mailbox meeting showing as tentative on OWA and outlook application
I have a licensed resource mailbox on cloud with delegates having full access. It is a hybrid environment
Whenever a meeting is booked the meeting is as tentative
The setting is set to auto accept and decline
AddNewRequestsTentatively is set to false
can you help me to know why the meeting is showing as tentative instead of busy

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
